# Adding files to newly created input[type='file'] tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it possible for my users to upload multiple files, one at a time. I am able to retrieve the files, but not add them to the input.

```
$('#ProductImages').change(function(event){
    let name = 'product[images][]';
    $('#ProductImagesFileNames').html(''); // reset preview images to empty
    var files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      let input = "<input multiple='multiple' type='file' name='" + name + "'>";
      $('#ProductImagesLabel').after(input);
      $(input)[0].files = files;
    }
```

I would like to have the input created with the files already attached.

Comment: `$(input)[0].files = files;` <= this line looks problematic.  You are taking the html, using jQuery to parse it into an Element, then trying to attach files to it.  After which, nothing is being done with the Element you created.  If you are trying to attach the files to the input you put in the DOM, then you need to look it up.

Comment: It's almost certainly illegal. You could create the input, hide it, and add the files programatically. The user wouldn't even know that the files were being uploaded

Comment: In this case I'm not sure if it is illegal or not.  The files are being grabbed off of another element.  Which for them to be on that other element, the user would have had to have selected them for that element.  @ControlAltDel

Comment: Looks like you're appending the input after #ProductImagesLabel and then adding the files to the input. What if you add the files first and then render the input element. TLDR: try swapping the last two lines.

Comment: @Taplar RE: grabbed off of another element - And there's no way a malicious programmer could spoof this? Surely you see the security issues with allowing this at all

Comment: @ControlAltDel as far as I'm aware, you cannot programatically create the elements that go in the files property.  You can remove them.  The question here is an uncertainty around if you can move them.  If you have some resources that indicate that a programmer can programatically create these objects I'd be interested in reading them.

Comment: @georgedum swapping the last two lines will not change anything on it's own, as `input` is a string.  The files property is not being adjusted on the string.  It's being adjusted on the Element created from the string, and then ignored.

Comment: Oh you're right @Taplar, maybe instead of a string you could use the document.createElement() method ?

Comment: Sure, that or simply store the `$(input)` in a variable, change the files on it, and then append it to the other element.  In any case, it just needs to use the correct thing.

Comment: @Taplar https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html none of this states explicitly that it can't be done in some other way, but it sure does make it seem unlikely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: @ControlAltDel https://jsfiddle.net/vkfend9L/  You cannot (or I could not figure out how to) move individual files, but you can replace the `files` property as a whole.